# What is the behavior of iscntrl?

Tags: c, character, standard-library

The function `iscntrl` is standardized. Unfortuneately on C99 we have:

> The iscntrl function tests for any control character

Considering the prototype which is `int iscntrl(int c);` I am expecting something like `true` for 0..31 and perhaps 127 too. However in the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("The ASCII value of all control characters are ");
    for (i=0; i<=1024; ++i)
    {
        if (iscntrl(i)!=0)
            printf("%d ", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

```
The ASCII value of all control characters are 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 127 264 288 308 310 320 334 
336 346 348 372 374 390 398 404 406 412 420 428 436 444 452 458 460 466 468 474 
476 484 492 500 506 512 518 530 536 542 638 644 656 662 668 682 688 694 700 706 
708 714 716 718 760 774 780 782 788 798 826 834 836 846 854 856 864 866 874 876 
882 888 890 892 898 900 908 962 968 970 988 994 1000
```

So I am wondering how this function is implemented behind the scene. I tried to search on the standard library, but the answer is not obvious.

https://github.com/bminor/glibc/search?q=iscntrl&unscoped_q=iscntrl

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are invoking undefined behavior by passing improper values to `iscntrl()`.

Per [**7.4 Character handling `<ctype.h>`**, paragraph 1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1):

> The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I agree with you, but the question is how it is implemented, to give these weird values?

Comment: @nowox It's a lookup table.  From [the comment in `ctype.h`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/7628a1b05adb1e4c6857b87c6f8b71a1d0b1d72c/ctype/ctype.h#L63):  "These point into arrays of 384, so they can be indexed by any `unsigned
   char` value [0,255]; by EOF (-1); or by any `signed char` value
   [-128,-1)."  You're passing values outside that range, so it's UB.

Comment: 'Tis a depressing reflection of the standard of C coding that they allocate the bytes for negative character offsets so bad code does not crash.  I observe that EOF (-1) is always classified as false for all the standard `isvwxyz()` tests — regardless of what the character with code -1 might be. That character is sometimes ÿ - a "Latin small letter y with diaeresis" in the Unicode standard, which would be classified lower-case, alphabetic, alphanumeric, printing and graphic (`islower()`, `isalpha()`, `isalnum()`, `isgraph()`, `isprint()`) if it were not preempted by the meaning for EOF.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler glibc accepts signed chars in order to minimise the amount of crashes in broken software, not to encourage you to pass signed chars. ÿ is not -1, it's 255, and if you pass 255, you'll get the correct answer. Assuming EOF=-1, a conforming C implementation is allowed to do anything if you call isalnum(-2) .

Comment: @KarolS — it's a pity that they feel they have to do that.  IMO, they shouldn't. They should call `abort()` when the function. is abused (since the behaviour is undefined, that's a legitimate response).  And it would make programmers sensibly careful.

Comment: @KarolS *glibc accepts signed chars in order to minimise the amount of crashes in broken software* "Paper over the problem and muddle along while crossing fingers and knocking on wood" is a horrible design concept.  It, umm, *encourage[s] you to pass signed chars* except for the inconsistent treatment of `EOF`.  *ÿ is not -1, it's 255* A distinction without a difference if you accept `signed char` inputs for `is*()`.  Interpreting 127 of 128 `signed char` values as `unsigned char` sure makes for an insidious corner-case bug should that one `signed char` value be encountered.

Comment: What is better: all programs running, just 0.001% of them misclassifying ÿ as not a letter, or 1% of programs hard crashing whenever they encounter a non-ASCII character? Keep in mind that fixing those programs was not an option. You can't just say "from now on, all broken programs will crash and die, so better write correctly!" without making tons of old broken programs crash and die.

Comment: @KarolS [**C*89***](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.3): "the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF..."  Glibc was released in 1992, which, on my calendar, is after 1989.

Comment: @AndrewHenle 1. People don't magically follow a newly released standard perfectly, especially before the internet era. 2. Glibc was also aiming at supporting existing old programs written as far as early 80s, if not even older. – So by design, they wanted as many broken programs, both old and new, to continue chugging along, as for vast majority of them the breakage was minimal and irrelevant.